# Error when trying to use xcolor package to define new colors

Tags: errors, color

I would really want to define some new colors, but it doesn't seem to work with the tutorials I found online. Could somebody please tell me what I'm doint wrong? Thanks!
Also, is there another way to create the color orchid?

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{comment} % enables the use of multi-line comments (\ifx \fi) 
\usepackage{fullpage} % changes the margin
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{}{}{}[]
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\newcommand*{\QEDB}{\hfill\ensuremath{\square}}%
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{Lila}{orchid!70!}


\begin{document}
```

Comment: Please post an example code that others can copy and paste, not screenshots. Why are you loading both color and xcolor (which supersedes color)?

Comment: ok I have. I am not sure what I'm supposed to do, I'm very new to LaTeX and still learning :)

Comment: For new users, I suggest starting with a blank document and adding packages when they are *needed*. It looks like you are using a template provided by someone else, which probably includes a lot of things you don't need, and is not a good way to get going.

Comment: I made my own template with the thing I needed at some moments but I'm never really sure which ones I need at what point that's why I use all. Why is this a problem? does it take up too much space or is it just unnecessary?

Comment: The more packages you load, the more complex things become, and the more likely you are to run into awkward problems. Learn to walk before you try to run!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two main problems:

- you have to load `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` before you load `\usepackage{tikz}`
- it should be `Orchid` not `orchid`

furthermore, please don't load packages multiple times.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{comment} % enables the use of multi-line comments (\ifx \fi) 
\usepackage{fullpage} % changes the margin
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{}{}{}[]
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\newcommand*{\QEDB}{\hfill\ensuremath{\square}}%
\usepackage{pgf}
%, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\colorlet{Lila}{Orchid!70!}


\begin{document}
 \color{Lila} test
\end{document}
```